# structured binding with existing vars not possible?

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

Is it possible to use already existing vars as target for return values in connection with `structured bindings`?

```
auto f()
{
    return std::make_tuple(1,2.2);
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    double z;

    [ x, z ] = f();  // Did not work in gcc 7.1

    // structured bindings only work with "new" vars?
    auto [a, b] = f();  // works fine
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use existing variables, you have `std::tie` for that purpose.

```
std::tie(x, z) = f(); // only works with tuples however
```

Structured bindings introduce new identifiers. Unfortunately there is nothing equivalent to `std::tie` for general aggregates.